# Android.mk: how do I list all *.c files in a particular directory?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In an `Android.mk` how do I list all `*.c` files in a particular directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose all `*.c*` files are kept under `<my_dir>/src`

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

MY_BASE_JNI_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)
MY_MODULE_DIR := $(shell basename $(LOCAL_PATH))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(subst $(MY_BASE_JNI_PATH)/$(MY_MODULE_DIR)/,,$(wildcard $(MY_BASE_JNI_PATH)/$(MY_MODULE_DIR)/src/*.c*))
```

Answer (score 3):

Like that:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-c-files-under, ./path/to/directory)
```